# Determine if the following set is a ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra

$R=\{a+b\sqrt[3]{3}:a,b\in\mathbb{Q}\}.$ Let $a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2\in\mathbb{Q}$

Addition: $$(a_1+b_1\sqrt[3]{3})+(a_2+b_2\sqrt[3]{3})=(a_1+a_2)+(b_1+b_2)\sqrt[3]{3}$$
Subtraction: $$(a_1+b_1\sqrt[3]{3})-(a_2-b_2\sqrt[3]{3})=(a_1-a_2)+(b_1+b_2)\sqrt[3]{3}$$
Multiplication: $$(a_1+b_1\sqrt[3]{3})\cdot(a_2+b_2\sqrt[3]{3})=\sqrt[3]{3}a_2b_1+\sqrt[3]{3}a_1b_2+a_1 a_2+\sqrt[3]{9}b_1 b_2$$
                   But $\sqrt[3]{9}∉Q[\sqrt[3]{3}]$

This is my attempt, basically $R=\{a+b\sqrt[3]{3}:a,b\in\mathbb{Q}\}$ I'm trying to determine if that is a Ring.

Comment: Use '\sqrt[n]{3}' for $\sqrt[n]{3}$

Comment: Um, what is your actual question?

Comment: It would seem then since $a_1a_2+b_1b_2\sqrt[3]{9}\notin{\mathbb{Q}}$ that it is not a ring...

Comment: @ChristopherErnst Thanks, that's what I was wondering if it was correct.

Since it's a not a ring it definitely can't be a field right?

And if it were a ring I would have to check for a multiplicative inverse? 

I'm just really unsure of the class I'm in.. sorry

Comment: No, rings do not necessarily need multiplicative inverses.  There are many types of rings; commutative rings, division rings, integral domains, fields, rings with unity, etc....the conditions for rings are they must form an abelian group under addition, multiplicative associativity must hold, and multiplication distributes over addition.  That is all you need for the standard ring definition.  Closure under both $+$ and $\cdot$ are required...

Comment: for clarity, fields are always rings, rings are not necessarily fields....

Comment: @ChristopherErnst Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You've pretty much discovered the simplest proof that this is not a ring. $\sqrt[3]{3}\in R,$ but $\sqrt[3]{3}\cdot\sqrt[3]{3}=\sqrt[3]{9}\notin R$, and so $R$ is not closed under multiplication.

It's worth noting that $R$ is a *group* (under addition), but is not a ring.